# When should I not exercise?

Tags: exercise, sleep, eating-habits

In relation to eating, when should I not exercise? Or rather, are there times that are better or worse than others to exercise during the day?

For example, is it better or worse to exercise in the morning? If you do it in the morning, should you do it before or after you eat? Should you wait for a while between you eat and exercise? Or at night, is it better or worse to exercise before you go to bed? Is it better or worse to do it before or after supper?

Maybe not the clearest question, but hopefully someone understand what I'm asking about. Basically, during a day, when taking sleeping and eating into account, when is it preferable to exercise or not to exercise?

Comment: Have a look at [this question regarding jogging before or after breakfast](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/3/8). I fear there is no 'best' answer, because you need to have to the time exercise at that moment as well. So it will be different for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Under normal circumstances you should be exercising after like 1,5-2 hours you have your meal, which should be consisting of complex carbs mainly.

When you wake up your glycogen level is so low in muscle cells. So if you wanna hit the gym in the morning, consume simple sugars. Because there are 2 opportunity windows to consume simple sugars.

One is right after you workout, the other one is right after you wake up.

So you may feel week if you don't eat anything and start exercising.

Liquid form is always absorbed faster, so drink fruit juice, eat couple tpbs of honey or something if you want to exercise after you wake up.

But overall, you can exercise any time of the day, doesn't matter much really.

If we are talking about bodybuilding, motivation is really important. So for example, after i get out of work my performance is a bit lower compared to the weekend. Although i consume same amount of protein and carbs, my motivation is low because of stress during the day.